# Docker image creation failed for Spring boot application with the error message failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c .mvnw dependency:go-offline"

Tags: spring-boot, docker, dockerfile

I am writing a multi-stage Dockerfile for a spring boot application. But the getting error.
Here is my Dockerfile command to build an image.

```
FROM maven:3.9.5-eclipse-temurin-17-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY .mvn/ .mvn
COPY mvnw pom.xml ./
RUN mvn dependency:go-offline
COPY ./src ./src
RUN ./mvnw clean install

FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jre-jammy
WORKDIR /opt/app
EXPOSE 8080
COPY --from=builder /opt/app/target/*.jar /opt/app/*.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/opt/app/*.jar" ]
```

Error message

```
 => [builder 4/7] COPY mvnw pom.xml ./                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => ERROR [builder 5/7] RUN ./mvnw dependency:go-offline                                                                                                                         0.3s 
------
 > [builder 5/7] RUN ./mvnw dependency:go-offline:
0.264 /bin/sh: ./mvnw: not found
------
Dockerfile:10
--------------------
   8 |     COPY .mvn/ .mvn
   9 |     COPY mvnw pom.xml ./
  10 | >>> RUN ./mvnw dependency:go-offline
  11 |     COPY ./src ./src
  12 |     RUN ./mvnw clean install
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c ./mvnw dependency:go-offline" did not complete successfully: exit code: 127
```

The error message is same when I am using `eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-jammy` image as a base image.

Comment: The most common causes of this sort of problem are the `mvnw` script incorrectly having DOS line endings, or the script referring to an interpreter like `#!/bin/bash` that isn't present in the Alpine-based image.  Have you checked both of these things?